# How do I get sar to show aggregate data for the whole month?

Tags: linux, monitoring, sar

We know that sar collects data iin /var/log/sa/sadd, where dd is the day of the month.
With the command  sar -A -f /var/log/sa/sadd > output.txt i can export data for a certain day of the month to open it in Ksar and analyze it.
Is it possible to export data for more than a day or for the whole month in a single output file ?

Comment: Why don't you iterate through the files and add data for each file into the output file ?

Comment: Thanks, this is what  i did and it worked. I thought that ksar won't be able to read a file created from multiple concatenated files.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I concatenated all files into one file and Ksar is able to read the big file.